# Symbolic link to a socket

Tags: permissions, security, symlink, socket

From a security point of view, is it safe to create a symbolic link to a socket file? The following bits of context refer to the deployment of a web application on a shared hosting service.

```
$ ls -al ~/runtime/supervisor
srwx------ 1 myuser myuser 0 Oct  6 20:02 supervisord.sock

$ pwd
~/runtime/deployment_1
$ ln -s ../supervisor/supervisor.sock
$ ls -al
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser myuser 47 Oct  6 21:20 supervisord.sock -> ../runtime/supervisor/supervisord.sock=
```

Should I set any special permissions on the symlink or something else?

Comment: I think it kinda depends on the application. For example, if the application deletes its socket when it shuts down gracefully, it will delete the symlink instead of the actual socket. Is this a security problem? Probably not since the only effect is that an old useless socket remains in the filesystem. I see it as more of a problem when the application restarts: it will probably recreate the socket in the wrong place. BTW, re: permissions: permissions are meaningless on symlinks.

Comment: What do you mean by “is it safe”? The existence of the symbolic link doesn't affect the socket itself, so any risk would come from the way the symlink is used. But you're not saying anything about how the symlink is used. What threats are you worried about? What are the different programs and users involved?

Comment: Sticky bit, sockets, symbolic links. These are concepts which I'm not very confident with. I just wanted to know if my configuration is safe, ie I don't want other users can access the socket through the symbolic link (rwxrwxrwx).

Answer (score 1):

As far as permissions go; you only need to be concerned with the permissions of the socket itself. Except on Mac/iOS, [chmod will either try to apply to the underlying file or not at all](https://superuser.com/a/303063/68745).